# kendo ui treeview with json speed issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

i have done kendo ui tree with external json file

this is working fine if i have nodes arround 200

but it is taking to much time if i have large amount of data

check this http://infinitelyinfinite.com/treeview/

here is my jQuery code

```
$.getJSON("/testTree.json", function (data) {
    $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
        dataSource: data
    });
})
```

and here is the sample of my `JSON` file

```
[
    {
        "id"   :100,
        "text" :"Region",
        "items":[
            {
                "id"   :1,
                "text" :"Asia",
                "parent_id" :100, 
                "items":[
                    {
                        "id"   :2,
                        "text" :"Central Asia",
                        "parent_id" :1, 
                        "items":[
                            {
                                "id"  :3,
                                "text":"Afghanistan",
                                "parent_id" :2, 
                            },
                            {
                                "id"  :4,
                                "text":"Azerbaijan",
                                "parent_id" :2, 
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "id"   :5,
                        "text" :"East Asia",
                        "parent_id" : 1,
                        "items":[
                            {
                                "id"  :6,
                                "text":"China"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id"   :7,
                "text" :"Europe",
                "parent_id" :100, 
                "items":[
                    {
                        "id"   :8,
                        "text" :"Central Europe",
                        "parent_id" :7, 
                        "items":[
                            {
                                "id"   :9,
                                "text" :"Austria",
                                "parent_id" :8, 
                                "items":[
                                    {
                                        "id"  :10,
                                        "parent_id" :9, 
                                        "text":"Carinthia"
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "id"   :11,
                                "text" :"Czech Republic",
                                "parent_id" :8, 
                                "items":[
                                    {
                                        "id"  :12,
                                        "text":"Carinthia",
                                        "parent_id" :11, 
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

is there any way to make it fast???
it is taking some time 30S or 40S

Comment: Do you need to load the complete tree at once? Can you retrieve first continents, Regions, Countries,...? That would allow to send only the data needed and HTML rendering would be much faster.

Comment: @Onbai no i dont want to load the complete tree at once you can download my json file from here [http://infinitelyinfinite.com/treeview/js/region_tree.json](http://infinitelyinfinite.com/treeview/js/region_tree.json)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
$.getJSON("/testTree.json", function (data) {
    $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
        dataSource: {
            data : data
        }
    });
});
```

Initializing the DataSource from an object instead of from an array seems to be much faster.

The code in your web-site would read (after some minor cleaning) as:

```
<head>
    <title> Json Tree</title>
    <link href="styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>

<div class="demo-section" style="float:left;">
    <h3 class="title">Select Continents</h3>

    <div id="treeview" class="demo-section"></div>
</div>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" charset=utf-8>
    //  $(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON("/js/region_tree.json", function (data) {
        $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
            dataSource    : {
                data: data
            },
            dataTextField : "text",
            dataValueField: "id"
        });
    });

    //  });
</script>
</body>
```

You might also do:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset=utf-8>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var tree = $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
            dataTextField : "text",
            dataValueField: "id"
        }).data("kendoTreeView");

        $.getJSON("/js/region_tree.json", function (data) {
            tree.dataSource.data(data);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Where after reading the `JSON` using `getJSON` I directly assign it to the `dataSource` of the tree.

Comment: i want document for this if you dont mind and can i use same logic for the multiple select in kendo ui ??? bdw thanks a lot you are life saviour .... :)

Comment: What kind of document do you want? AFAIK, this is actually not documented but something that I found while "playing" with you huge data. It is likely that this is some sort of side-effect caused on how the treat Arrays and Objects in a DataSource. But this is something that only KendoUI developers can answer...

Comment: can i use the same concept for `kendoMultiSelect` i also want to search from json file so ..??

Comment: You can what I don't know is if the result will be the same. I did not take a look into Kendo UI code so this speed improvement is **not** documented and might change in future implementations. Here we should have some of Kendo UI folks saying the last word.